# QML - How to get children in an item?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I had a problem with the item in QML. I wanna get children of an item but it seems working in the first element.

The detail code is below:

I have a gridview with a list custom component AAA_Styles

```
GridView{
    id: grdViewDeviceControl
    clip: true
    interactive: true
    ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator{}
    cellWidth: 200
    cellHeight: 300

    model: ListModel{}

    delegate: Item {
        width: grdViewDeviceControl.cellWidth
        height: grdViewDeviceControl.cellHeight
        AAA_Styles{
            id: deviceControl
            objectName: "deviceControl"
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            name: Names
            subname: Subnames
    }
}
```

My custom **AAA_RTS** is a *QML* component have some *functions* such as:
- function_a()
- function_b()
I added 2 items into model using

> grdViewDeviceControl.model.append()

I ensure the model have data that I added because It appeared in my design and the count of gridview is 2 elements

> console.log(grdViewDeviceControl.count) //the result is 2

After that, I tried to get each element to access functions that they are available using a method in signal ***onRelease*** of a button:

```
onReleased: {
    console.log("number of item: " + grdViewDeviceControl.count)
    var myRTS = grdViewDeviceControl.contentItem.children[0]
    console.log(myRTS)
    console.log(myRTS.children[0])
    myRTS = grdViewDeviceControl.contentItem.children[1]
    console.log(myRTS)
    console.log(myRTS.children[1])
}
```

The result on console:

> qml: number of item: 2
>   qml: QQuickItem(0x9828f60)
>   qml: AAA_Styles_QMLTYPE_0_QML_112(0x9829070, "deviceControl")
>   qml: QQuickItem(0x5554140)
>   qml: **undefined**

With the first element ***grdViewDeviceControl.contentItem.children[0]***, I access **function_a** or **function_b** successful but when I using the second the error appeared

> *TypeError: Cannot call method 'function_a' of undefined*

So can anyone tell me why I wrong and how to fix it?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: It is a bad practice to access the items in a view since it brings problems such as what you point out, instead you should interact with the model information. Why do you want to access the items?

Comment: Yes, I don't know the best way to do that. Thank you for the recommendation and how to access the model? I guess I have to create a model outside of **gridview** and access it by ***id***

Comment: Exactly, check an old answer from me https://stackoverflow.com/a/55318200/6622587

Comment: I tried your way but I don't want to get model properties, I want to access all properties of my custom `AAA_RTS` such as `function_a` or `function_b`. The result when I use `myModel.get(0)` is _qml: QObject(0x76180840)_ and `myModel.get(1)` is _qml: QObject(0x761808f0)_. I don't know what must I do continues?

Comment: **You do not have to pass the objects from delegate to the model, but the value of the properties of the objects of delegate to model**. Then create empty properties and have a binding with the properties of the component, for example in my code I did `onTextChanged: model.text = tf.text`, so the text property of some item of the model will change when the TextField text changes . In conclusion, it maps the properties of the delegate elements with the properties of each item in the model.

Comment: `My component` inside an `Item`, you can check the code above to see that. I think when we use `model.get(index)` or `gridlayout.contentItem.children(index)` like me used we only access to the `Item` not `my component`. My model made delegate changing with properties of data input but how about `function` of my component? You mean that I have to create some function in `Item` to call functions of the component after access to `Item` using these functions will mapping to the component's functions?

Comment: The possible solution that you indicate can work but I am not analyzing it because for me it is not the correct solution since it is difficult to maintain, for example if you change the component you will have to modify another part of the code. That is, your possible solution is a temporary patch that in the future will give you many headaches (I already had them when I started with QML and I do not want to have them again). For me you have a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), that is, you are asking for an answer that no one guarantees works, instead of your underlying problem.

Comment: Is my understanding of the `model` seems a database? To maintain it easier editable and more consistency we should make isolation with component?

Comment: 1) The information in the database is considered a model. The model in general is the information that manages the business logic. 2) Exactly, each component must be like a black box: only expose the properties that are used as inputs and serve as output, the internal mechanisms should not be exposed.

Comment: For example, in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55483615/6622587 I have created several components that only expose some properties. at the end the IconPane component only exposes the url and the name, the rest is not exposed

Comment: To slowly reply, I really thank for your link `XY problem`. I very excited it and realize many many things that I must to do with any questions next time. It's really useful for me.

Comment: I think the comments have already been extended. The last thing I'll say is that you first design your components before implementing them. Many times we have the bad habit of writing code without having a clear vision of what is desired (the design), read [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377) bye

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to access directly to the child items. Use delegate IDs, signals and slots instead:

- Give a "delegate ID" to all your delegates through the model of your `GridView`.
- In your `GridView`, add signals that will be used to broadcast to all the delegates the following things:

  - The "delegate ID" of the delegate that you want it to execute the function.
  - The arguments for the `AAA_Styles` function.
- In your delegate, add one slot per `AAA_Styles` function. Each slot will execute the `AAA_Styles` function only if the broadcasted delegate ID is the delegate's: `if (broadcastedID === delegateID) { function_ab() }`.
- When you want to execute `function_a()` or `function_b()` in a delegate, broadcast the delegate ID and the function arguments through the corresponding `GridView` signal (in `onReleased`, for example).

The following piece of code sums up what I have just described to you. If it does not work put the delegate in a separated QML file. This should work for good:

```
// Your grid
GridView {
    id: grdViewDeviceControl
    clip: true
    interactive: true
    ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator {}
    cellWidth: 200
    cellHeight: 300

    model: ListModel {
        /*
            Example of list element:
            ListElement { m_uuid: "{element-uuid}" }
        */
    }

    delegate: Item {
        width: grdViewDeviceControl.cellWidth
        height: grdViewDeviceControl.cellHeight

        AAA_Styles {
            id: deviceControl
            objectName: "deviceControl"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            name: Names
            subname: Subnames
        }

        // The delegate ID
        property string delegate_id: m_uuid

        // Broadcast receivers
        function delfunc_a(uuid, argA0) {
            if (uuid === this.delegate_id) {
                deviceControl.function_a(argA0)
            }
        }

        function delfunc_b(uuid, argB0, argB1) {
            if (uuid === this.delegate_id) {
                deviceControl.function_b(argB0, argB1)
            }
        }

        // Connecting broadcasters to receivers
        Component.onCompleted: {
            grdViewDeviceControl.exec_a.connect(this.delfunc_a)
            grdViewDeviceControl.exec_b.connect(this.delfunc_b)
        }

        Component.onDestruction: {
            grdViewDeviceControl.exec_a.disconnect(this.delfunc_a)
            grdViewDeviceControl.exec_b.disconnect(this.delfunc_b)
        }
    }

    // Your broadcasters
    signal exec_a(string uuid, int argA0)
    signal exec_b(string uuid, bool argB0, string argB1)
}
```

```
// Somewhere else in your code:
onReleased: {
    /*
     * Only the delegate whose ID is "{a-given-uuid}"
     * will execute deviceControl.function_a(3):
     */
    grdViewDeviceControl.exec_a("{a-given-uuid}", 3)
    /*
     * Only the delegate whose ID is "{another-given-uuid}"
     * will execute deviceControl.function_b(true, "U got style!"):
     */
    grdViewDeviceControl.exec_b("{another-given-uuid}", true, "U got style!")
}
```