# Is Qml able to receive a list of models and let listview to choose which one to use?

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

I have got one listview in qml now known as listview1. For each element in listview1, it contains another listview used to show some of its variables. Now I want to make it possible for all such sub-listviews able to add items to them. And also adding item to one of them will not affect all the other listviews in other elements of listview1.

What is the best way to solve such problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604525/1493608 (same thing but with a `GridView` instead of a `ListView`) :

- Give each sub-`ListView` a UUID.
- Connect each sub-`ListView` to a `listview1` signal that you will use to broadcast to sub-`ListView` delegates what you will want to do.
- In this signal, put your UUID.
- In sub-`ListView` receivers, put a filter on the UUID and do what you want to do only if it is the right one.

```qml
ListView {
    id: listview1

    signal broadcaster(string uuid, var other_args)

    delegate: ListView {
        // Provided like this or as a role from the corresponding list element
        property string uuid: ""

        signal sendToOtherLV(string uuid, var other_args)

        function lv_receiver(broadcasted_uuid, other_args) {
            if (this.uuid === broadcasted_uuid) {
                // Do what you have to do with other_args.
            }
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            /*
             * Custom way to generate the UUID and store it so
             * the other ListViews will be able to retrieve it.
             */
            this.uuid = generateAndStoreUUID()

            // Connecting the sub-ListView to your "sub-ListView LAN".
            this.sendToOtherLV.connect(listview1.broadcaster)
            listview1.broadcaster.connect(this.lv_receiver)
        }

        Component.onDestruction: {
            // Disconnecting the sub-ListView from your "sub-ListView LAN".
            this.sendToOtherLV.disconnect(listview1.broadcaster)
            listview1.broadcaster.disconnect(this.lv_receiver)
        }

        // Here is an example of what you might have to do
        function foo() {
            // ...

            var otherlv_receiver_uuid
            var signal_args

            // Retreive the UUID of the ListView that you want to send something to.
            // Set the other arguments you want to send through the signal.

            this.sendToOtherLV(otherlv_receiver_uuid, signal_args)

            // ...
        }

        // Other sub-ListView-related stuff
    }

    // Other listview1-related stuff
}
```